# Flatten tuples in a nested list

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples

is there a compact oneliner or python idiom to handle the following task?

I want to transform a list of list of tuples like this:

```
input = [[(1,2,3),(4,5,6)],[(7,8,9),(10,11,12)]]
```

to this:

```
output [[1,2,3,7,8,9], [4,5,6,10,11,12]]
```

Using map and flattening the list only gave me the follwing

```
input_trans = map(list, zip(*input))
input_trans_flat = [item for sublist in input_trans for item in sublist]
Out: [(1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 9), (4, 5, 6), (10, 11, 12)]
```

Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: next time, don't shadow  the `input()` function with your variable name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do:

```
output = [list(a + b) for a, b in zip(*input)]
```

The `zip` part, as you already know, transposes the outer list of lists. Then I grab each pair of tuples and concatenate them, then turn the combined tuple into a list. If you don't care if you have a list of lists or a list of tuples in the end, you could get rid of the `list` call.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to generalise [Blckknght's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46153039/4909087) to any number of tuples inside a list, using `sum`.

```
output = [list(sum(x, ())) for x in zip(*input)]
print(output)
```

---

```
[[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: Yes indeed I needed a generalised solution. I tested it in the meanwhile this solution:    
    [list(chain.from_iterable(_)) for _ in zip(*data)]. 
But yours was nearly twice as fast when measured with timeit. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) like below:

```
output = [[item for tup in (i, j) for item in tup] for i, j in zip(*input)]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> input = [[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], [(7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)]]
>>>
>>> output = [[item for tup in (i, j) for item in tup] for i, j in zip(*input)]
>>> output
[[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way.

```
from itertools import chain
l = [[(1,2,3),(4,5,6)],[(7,8,9),(10,11,12)]]
[list(chain.from_iterable(s)) for s in l]
```

gives me

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
```